# onProgressChanged doesnot hit 100% on heavy sites

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview

**Chrome/WebView version: 53 and 54 beta**

Example URL:
bbc.com , cnn.com

**Steps to reproduce the problem:**

1. launch a webview based application with chrome / webview 53 installed
2. load bbc.com or cnn.com
3. wait for the page load to complete

**What is the expected behavior?**
onProgressChanged() gets called from the start of the page till it reaches 100

**What went wrong?**
the page load is complete and WebViewClient.onPageFinished() is called. But the progress reported at WebChromeClient.onProgressChanged() stops at around 94-98 but never hits 100.

**Did this work before?** Yes Chrome/WebView version 51

I've a webview based application and the progress bar for loading is tied to the onProgressChanged() callback in the WebChromeClient. Until like a week back, things were all fine. But now, it never hits 100% page load. On investigation, i found that it still works fine on a device with the webview/Chrome version is 51. but it fails on a similar device where the webview/Chrome version is 53. i even tested with Chrome beta 54 installed and it still seems to be broken with the WebViewClient.onProgressChanged() callback as it never hits 100%.

but this happens only on heavy sites. like bbc, cnn, npr.com etc.. yahoo, google, bing etc still loads fine and progress reported reaches 100%.

this happens on all native webview based browsers i guess. It happens in Javelin, Maxathon browser and also in my webview based app.

Anyone facing similar issues?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind. Chromium accpected my bug.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=650781

Comment: is this bug fixed now?

Comment: ya this was fixed long time back i believe. i dont see the issue anymore and the issue is marked as fixed in 2016